# Bootstrap Confirmation Does not work with ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Where is the possible problem, I have a service that returns a json, use this returns to ride my table.

If I leave the statisc record it works the plugin as confirmation code below:

```
<td><strong>Fatura Abril</strong><br /> Este é um aviso de que sua fatura do mÊs 04 está vencendo</td>                                      
<td class="text-right"></a> 
 <a data-toggle="confirmation" class="label label-danger" type="button" id="not-basic"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
</td>
```

But if you use function to return and assemble the data via json, the table is monstada but the plugin confirmation does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var url="phptabela.php"; // PHP File
    //var url="getposts.json"; // JSON File

    $.getJSON(url,function(data){

        console.log(data);
        $.each(data.data, function(i,post){

        var newRow =
        "<tr>"

        +"<td><strong>"+post.titulo+"</strong><br />" +post.texto+"</td>"   
        +"<td class='text-right'></a> "
        +"<a data-toggle='confirmation' class='btn btn-default label label-danger' type='button' id='not-basic'> "
        +"<i class='fa fa-times'></i></a> "
        +"</td>"


        +"</tr>" ;
        $(newRow).appendTo("#json-data");
        });
    });
}); 
</script>
```

I am using this plugin:
http://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org/

Comment: Using an html ID in a loop is never a good idea because ID's have to be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you receive the data from ajax and append it to `json-data` you need to initialise the new confirmation

From doc I can see that you need to do this :

```
$('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
  rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]',
  // other options
});
```